# dynamic key value for data in sqlite storage (Ionic 3, Cordova, Angular 5)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I’m trying to save several data array object to sqlite storage.
I can manage to save just one but whenever I try to save another one, it overrides previous one with the same key name. I have to make the key value dynamic. How can I do that?

Here’s my data provider ts file.

```
private options: any[] = [

    {
      "name": "option 01",
      "website": "www.google.com",
      "about": "choose this option 01",
      "id": "1"
    },

    {
      "name": "option 02",
      "website": "www.yahoo.com",
      "about": "choose this option 02",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "option 03",
      "website": "www.bing.com",
      "about": "choose this option 03",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "option 04",
      "website": "www.stackoverflow.com",
      "about": "choose this option 04",
      "id": "4"
    }
]
```

and here’s my home.ts file. It saves data object well but right now, it can save only one.
I want to be able to save several and delete each dynamically using different key value per a data object.

```
  setValue(){
    this.storage.set("object",this.option).then((successData)=>{
      console.log("Data Stored!");
      console.log(successData);
    })
  }
  getValue(){
    this.storage.get("object").then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  removeValue() {
    this.storage.remove("object").then((data)=> {
      console.log("data removed!");
    })
  }
```

Thanks in advance, Ideally, I’m looking into save several data objects into the same key value with different ids… but unfortunately, if a key value is same, it will override the previous data object.

Comment: are you want to save different option or not?? if update option array in saving time in a object it's resolve your problem or not?? suppose you have firstly 4 array object then another 2 array object came then its will be 6.

Comment: I want to save different options.. would you please show me some code for that? now I can save only one..

Comment: If you update option value before save then its will require only one object .. is your any reason for save different objects ?

Comment: I need to be able to save different options to a list..  so there any way to save different options to one "object" ? or is there a way to assign different ids to options?

Comment: Different option mean option1 have 4 array elements option 2  have 3 elements??

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Storing more than one value is no different in this context than any other

Comment: Yeah.. maybe I'm not fully understanding this. What I'm trying to do is saving each "options" in data array as a different item in sqlite database. How can I do that? because when I create a save button with this.storage.set();, it allows me to save into only one key value. It won't save more than one data object.

Comment: Either make the value an array or object that actually represents multiple values, in which case you would retrieve it then add a value and then store it again, or create a unique key

Comment: Also, FYI, do **not** write `options: any[] = [something]`. That is reprehensibly awful code. Write `options = [something]` instead.

Comment: thanks, I will try options = []   .. ideally I want to use option's name as key value so I can later remove it easily.  But it looks like set() can take only string value as key.. it's confusing..

Comment: If it only accepts a string, then you need to use a string. you might convert an object into a string by using `JSON.stringify`.  You'll need to parse it after you retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing more context here but just try to make your funcitons to accept unique key name of option you need (I called it optionNumber).

See below.

```js
setValue(optionNumber){
    this.storage.set("option"+optionNumber,this.options[optionNumber]).then((successData)=>{
      console.log("Data Stored!");
      console.log(successData);
    })
  }
  getValue(optionNumber){
    this.storage.get("option"+optionNumber).then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  removeValue(optionNumber) {
    this.storage.remove("option"+optionNumber).then((data)=> {
      console.log("data removed!");
    })
  }
```

Now once you have your options array (this.options) with data, when you need to store specific option just do:

setValue(0)

Please note since array index starts at 0, you might need to adjust for that if you can't have option 0.